# How to put 'selected' in html options based on data in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am developing an angularJS. Here is my code in PHP:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">Do you have the right to work in UK?</div>
    <select name="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk" ng-model="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="yes" <?php echo $user->do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk == 'yes' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Yes</option>
        <option value="no" <?php echo $user->do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk == 'no' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>No</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Considering that the variable {{user_data.do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk}} holds 'yes' or 'no'. What would be the equalent of my PHP code in angularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy you don't need to add condition in option select. Instead  only setting `ng-model="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk"` should have worked as

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk =  "no"
});
```

```html
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">Do you have the right to work in UK?</div>
    <select name="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk" ng-model="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no" >No</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instated of **selected** only use **selected="selected"**. This adds selected attribute to the option.

```
<option value="yes" <?php echo $user->do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk == 'yes' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Yes</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

```
<select name="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk" ng-model="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="yes" ng-selected="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk === 'yes'">Yes</option>
  <option value="no" ng-selected="do_you_have_the_right_to_work_in_uk === 'no'">No</option>
</select>
```